# different behaviour for current location latitude and longitude in iOS7 to IOS8

Tags: ios, ios7, gps, xamarin, locationmanager

Using xamarin for current location [currentLocation example](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_4_ios_backgrounding_walkthroughs/location_walkthrough/)
I used the above Link for getting current location latitude and longitude.
In IOS 7  before upgrade to IOS 8 Its shows my current location latitude and longitude on both simulator and device.(Its looks strange for me in simulator for getting current location latitude and longitude).

After upgrade to iOS 8 and run same code it give

In simulator:(Turn on wifi no sim card location service App always.)

```
Result:
latitude = 37.785834.
longitude = -122.406517.
```

On Device IPhone5c (Turn on wifi no sim card location service App always.)

```
Result:
latitude = 37.785834.
longitude = -122.406517.
```

(But I expected my current location latitude and longitude )

After upgrade it does not ask, that application like use the Your Current Location GPS. an Alert message with YES, NO options.

How to get my current location latitude and longitude?

Comment: I have never had the simulator return any location other than the location set through debug or the location menu in the simulator.  Check that you haven't forced a simulated location in Xcode debug - this will apply to both simulator and the device

Comment: When run the application on simulator its shows Result:
latitude = 37.785834.
longitude = -122.406517.   When run on Device  (Iphone5c) location services Location.IOS (Application Name) selected check Allow Location Access Always  and open the app                         Result: Latitude : [lat] longitude: [lon].... Its does not work does not show current location latitude and longitude.

Comment: I guess there is some thing wrong with locationManger.  Unable to get current location latitude and longitude.  Please let me know how to get current location latitude and longitude. using LocationManager xamarin for IOS.

Comment: Hello Dear, Did you figured out this issue in simulator ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to request permission explicitly from iOS 8.0 onwards. The steps to do so:

1. Update your Info.plist file. Insert a new key: either *NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription* or *NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription* keys and write the custom message that will be displayed when your app requests the permission.

It is a must to have either of these keys in your plist file otherwise the permission request won't be displayed! If you don't want to show a custom explanation text in the alertview, leave the key's value string empty, but you still must have the key present in the Info.plist file!

2. Before you start tracking, check that you are on iOS8 then send either RequestAlwaysAuthorization  or RequestWhenInUseAuthorization from the CLLocationManager instance. Example:

   ```
   var locationManager = new CLLocationManager();
   if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
       locationManager.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();
   }
   ```

In this case, use the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key in your Info.plist file. Please note, Xamarin Studio does not currently offer you this key automatically from the dropdown list, you have to enter / copy-paste this key manually there.

Comment: 2 additional things to consider:

If you use Xamarin.Mobile (instead of CLLLocationManager directly) then replace step #2 with just making sure you have the latest (post ios8) update to the Xamarin.Mobile component too. Existing projects will not automatically update to it. Then, just calling StartListening on the Geolocator will kick in the prompt.

I also discovered the Maps app wasn't even getting the custom coordinate I'd set for the simulator to use. So had to nudge the simulator location back to working by turning the custom location to "None", and then back to the custom location.

Comment: Not Working for me. I have done these all. I am getting the same location (latitude = 37.785834.
longitude = -122.406517)

Answer (score 2):

When using the iOS simulator you need to set the custom location for the simulator hardware. Go to Debug, select location, custom location and then set the preferred co-ordinates.

Comment: I believe you ARE correct!  : )  In fact, the instructor in the course I'm taking even specifically says that the Apple Headquarters coordinates are the expected returned values (probably by default) of the simulator in use, and that these were the values she was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Add In LocationManger.cs file for method `LocationManager`

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
    this.locMgr.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();
}
```

After change

```
public LocationManager ()
{
    this.locMgr = new CLLocationManager();
    LocationUpdated += PrintLocation;
    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
        this.locMgr.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();
    }
}
```

Add Info Plist manually NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription empty string.

Then clean the build and run the application.  Its shows my current location latitude and longtidu.

Answer (score 0):

I tried above solutions but that did not work. Problem is when you are targeting IOS >= 9.0 then Location manager change some permission variables, which are supposed to mention explicitly in info.pList.

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Why you need Location</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Why you need Location</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Why you need Location</string>

<key>NSLocationWhileInUsage</key>
<string>Why you need Location</string>
```

use these four keys if you want to target  all versions .. before and after 9.0.

Also note that this line means whether user is in foreground or background use locations (apple discourage this because it has potential of privacy) [check documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620551-requestalwaysauthorization)

```
[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

whereas this means,

```
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

Only use when app is in foreground [check documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620562-requestwheninuseauthorization)